# Java triangle prints with stars, that starts with the start number

Tags: java

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                     
    triangle.shape(9);                                                                      
    triangle.shape(12);                                                                         
  }                                     
}

public class triangle                                   
{                                       
  public static void shape(int v)                                       
  {                                     
    for(int i=0; i < v; i++)                                        
    {                                       
      for(int a= v-1; a > i; a--)                                       
        System.out.print(" ");                                      
      for(int a= i*2;a >= 0;a--)                                        
        System.out.print("*");                                      
      System.out.println();                                     

      if(v <= 0)                                        
      {                                     
        System.out.println("Error");                                        
      }                                     
    }                                       
  }                                     
}
```

I am a basic learner, I am trying to implement a triangle shape, where if 9 was chosen, it would start from 9 stars e.g. 9,7,5,3,1, but if an even number is inputted, it would go down by 1, so 10 would become 9, allowing 9,7,5,3,1 pattern and anything that is 1 or less is error. So I have tried implementing a similar case with the help of resources, but my output is the length of rows, how so would I have to do in order to achieve my target?

Comment: why is that "error" in your loop?

Comment: How exactly is your triangle supposed to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. See code comments for explanations.

```
package main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        shape(9);
        shapeReverse(9);
        shape(12);
        shapeReverse(12);
    }

    public static void shape(int v) {

        // check if v is less than or equal to 1
        if (v <= 1) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            return;
        }

        // check if v is even or odd
        // if even then decrement by 1
        // if odd then do nothing
        v = v % 2 == 0 ? v - 1 : v;

        // declare and initialize a counter for spaces
        int space = 0;

        // loop until v is less than or equal to 0
        while (v > 0) {

            // print out the spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            // print out the *
            for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            // decrement v by 2 since each level of the triangle has a difference of 2
            // asterisk
            v = v - 2;

            // increment space by 1 since each level of the triangle starts at different
            // positions
            space++;

            // print a new line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void shapeReverse(int v) {

        // check if v is less than or equal to 1
        if (v <= 1) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            return;
        }

        int tmp = 1;

        // declare and initialize a counter for spaces
        int space = v % 2 == 0 ? (v / 2) - 1 : (v / 2);

        // loop until tmp is less than or equal to v
        while (tmp <= v) {

            // print out the spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            // print out the *
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            // increment t by 2 since each level of the triangle has a difference of 2
            // asterisk
            tmp = tmp + 2;

            // decrement space by 1 since each level of the triangle starts at different
            // positions
            space--;

            // print a new line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Sample input:

```
shape(9);
```

Sample output:

```
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

Sample input:

```
shape(12);
```

Sample output:

```
***********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```

Sample input:

```
shapeReverse(9);
```

Sample output:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Sample input:

```
shapeReverse(12);
```

Sample output:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Comment: Ahh and if I were to change the shape? Meaning going upwards?

Comment: @davyJ I have added a method that will make the triangle face upwards

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static void shape(int v) {
    if (v <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    } else {
        for (int i = v; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int a = i; a < v; a++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int a = i; a > 0; a--)
                System.out.print("* ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I modified shape method to print downward triangle, but your code don't handle even number input.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code provide a method public static void shape(int v) to us. This method let us input a int value, this value determine how many rows will be print. You want to have method to input a int value to control the max starts in a line. So there is a map between these 2 method. And then I have provide a methods public static int setMaxStartsInRow(int starts) to convert the max starts in a line to the rows of the shape. For example, we want to control the max starts number for a line is 9. The result is triangle should have 4 rows. My method int setMaxStartsInRow(int starts) input 9 and get 4 as result to match your requirement.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // triangle.shape(9);                                                                      
        // triangle.shape(12);  
        triangle.shape(triangle.setMaxStartsInRow(9));  
        // triangle.shape(triangle.setMaxStartsInRow(11));  
    }

}


public class triangle {


    public static void shape(int v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            for (int a = v - 1; a > i; a--)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int a = i * 2; a >= 0; a--)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();

            if (v <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    public static int setMaxStartsInRow(int starts) {

        if (starts <= 1)
            throw new RuntimeException("Input Max Number of starts should be greater than 1");

        int validateStarts = 0;

        if (starts % 2 == 0) {
            validateStarts = starts - 1;
        } else {
            validateStarts = starts;
        }

        return validateStarts / 2 + 1;
    }
}
```

Result for triangle.shape(triangle.setMaxStartsInRow(9));

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Result for triangle.shape(triangle.setMaxStartsInRow(10));

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Result for triangle.shape(triangle.setMaxStartsInRow(9));

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Result for triangle.shape(triangle.setMaxStartsInRow(1));

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Input Max Number of starts should be greater than 1
            at triangle.setMaxStartsInRow(triangle.java:25)
            at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code :

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){
        shape(5);
        shape(12);
    }
    public static void shape(int v)
    {
        if(v%2 == 0){
            v=--v;
        }
        int count = v;
        int round = v;
        if (v > 0 ) {
        for(int i=v; i >0; i=i-2) {
            for (int a = 0 ; a<=(round-count) ;a++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int a = i ; a>0;a--)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
            count = --count;
        }
    }
        else
            System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```